# Determine the exact value of $\cos(x−\pi)+\cos\left(x−\frac \pi2\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Consider $x  \in(\pi; 2\pi)$ such that $\;3\cos\left(\dfrac x2\right)=-\sqrt2$

Determine the exact value of $\cos(x-\pi)+\cos\left(x-\dfrac\pi2\right)$.

I can't seem to find a way of solving this, Ii have tried using the angle summation formulas, etc.

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: Please don't remove modifications done to improve the layout of your post.

Comment: @idk I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the duplication formula,

$$\cos x=2\left(-\frac{\sqrt2}{3}\right)^2-1=-\frac59=-\cos(x-\pi)$$
and
$$\sin x=-2\frac{\sqrt2}{3}\sqrt{1-\left(-\frac{\sqrt2}{3}\right)^2}=-\frac{2\sqrt{14}}9=\cos(x-\frac\pi2).$$

(We take the positive sign for the sine because $x$ is known to exceed $\pi$.)

Answer (score -1):

**HINT:**

[Compound Angle Formulae](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/higher/maths/trigonometry/compound_and_multiple_angles/revision/2/)

$$\cos(A\pm B) \equiv \cos A \cos B \mp \sin A \sin B$$